# Beautify cannot indent my HTML after PHP in Brackets

Tags: php, html, adobe-brackets, js-beautify

i know that beautify cannot indent properly PHP. All I want is that it skips it, because i get strange spaces after PHP code inside the page.

Here's a screenshot :

[image: screenshot]

I have been trying a lot of plugins, looking around for hour, i'm getting mad !

Anyone may help ? 
thanks :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>MicroCMS - Home</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>MicroCMS</h1>
    </header>

    <?php foreach ($articles as $article) : ?>
        <article>
            <h2><?php echo $article['art_title']; ?></h2>
            <p>
                <?php echo $article['art_content']; ?>
            </p>
        </article>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

            <footer>
                <a href="http://www.test.fr/">MircroCMS</a> is a student work
            </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @DanieleFois here it is :)

Comment: It does the same on mine...

Answer (score 0):

I found an add-on for Brackets.io that uses auto-indent called **Indentator**.

It uses shortcut keys  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

1. First go to **File** > **Extension Manager** and search for **Indentator**.
2. Upon completion of installation, use <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> and it should work without issue.